# css3 text rotation

Tags: html, css, rotation

How do I flip the text horizontally in my code.

When I try the -90deg in plain code, it is working but it is not working when I add that into my working sample. Currently I have h3 text rotated but I need tat to be faced to the left (Means flip it horizontaly)

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pJDLG/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transform: scaleX(-1);
```

You don't use rotate for flipping, you use scale - `scaleX(-1)` for flipping horizontally, `scaleY(-1)` for flipping vertically - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3447277).

---

In your example however, what you do need is a `-90deg` rotate, remove the `transform-origin`(let it take its default value) and change the `margin`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/pJDLG/25/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use positive values.

Also see here:

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-transform

Example:

```
p {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: But it is not working in my code. I think there is some conflict ion. So i wanted my code to be edited

Comment: i am using chrome 21. in my browser it is working, i have tried it on your jsfiddle. Or maybe i misunderstood you. can you an example anywhere?